# Akka.net starting and stopping with no activity

Tags: c#, scala, akka, .net-4.5, akka.net

I'm trying to send a message from a typesafe akka actor in Scala (2.4.11) to Akka.net actor in C# (1.0.4)

I have a weird problem with my  .Net actor, it keeps saying started then stopped, but I have no clue whats happening under the hood:

A piece of Akka.net log:

```
2015-11-18 16:23:57.6168|DEBUG|Akka.Remote.Transport.ProtocolStateActor|Started (Akka.Remote.Transport.ProtocolStateActor)
2015-11-18 16:24:27.6578|DEBUG|Akka.Remote.Transport.ProtocolStateActor|Stopped
2015-11-18 16:24:42.6344|DEBUG|Akka.Remote.Transport.AkkaProtocolManager|now supervising akka://converter/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp.0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3a%2f%2fconverter%40192.168.56.1%3a60161-107
2015-11-18 16:24:42.6344|DEBUG|Akka.Remote.Transport.ProtocolStateActor|Started (Akka.Remote.Transport.ProtocolStateActor)
2015-11-18 16:25:12.6871|DEBUG|Akka.Remote.Transport.ProtocolStateActor|Stopped
2015-11-18 16:25:27.6402|DEBUG|Akka.Remote.Transport.AkkaProtocolManager|now supervising akka://converter/system/transports/akkaprotocolmanager.tcp.0/akkaProtocol-tcp%3a%2f%2fconverter%40192.168.56.1%3a60162-108
2015-11-18 16:25:27.6402|DEBUG|Akka.Remote.Transport.ProtocolStateActor|Started (Akka.Remote.Transport.ProtocolStateActor)
```

It's doing the start/stop on every message sent, but actor doesn't execute, how can I probably check whats happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not going to work; Akka.NET and Akka are not wire format compatible with one another.

This may change in the future, but currently they are not.

Comment: What exactly is the current degree of difference between the two? Is it related to .NET and Scala type systems differences (meaning cannot send .NET objects to Scala and vice-versa) or is more deep, like the message format itself being completely incompatible. My point is, can the two be made to communicate using simple types as messages (like strings and bytes) at the current stage?

Comment: The two VMs being very different is one thing, but for Akka internal protocols we use Google Protocol Buffers so that's less of a concern actually. Technically the serialization could be made work. However anything that contains a classname is JVM specific for example, like remote deployment etc. The more scary question is more about *semantic* equivalence, since clustering etc. are not publicly defined protocols/apis, it's something the .NET impl. has tried to "match" but we can not be sure it actually would without extensive testing and effort, which would need to be backed by customer needs

Comment: Thank you for the details, @Konrad. Indeed, I did not take into account, when forming the cluster, the two systems had to heartbeat each other at a point, and that might involve communication that in incompatible format. I hope the two are one day made to work together